# Javascript Inline and External Script difference

Tags: javascript, wordpress, performance

I need some help, I am currently porting all my internal scripts on my website to a single `js` file to speed up my website according to the Google and Yahoo page speed recommendations.

I have the following script in my page footer.php (I am using wordpress)

```
<script> (function ($) {
jQuery(function () {
    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.box',
            columnWidth: 100
        });
    });
    $container.infinitescroll({
        navSelector: '.post-nav',
        nextSelector: '.previous a',
        itemSelector: '.box',
        loading: {
            finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
            img: '/wp-content/themes/images/ajax-loader.gif'
        }
    },

    function (newElements) {
        var $newElems = $(newElements).css({
            opacity: 0
        });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function () {
            $newElems.animate({
                opacity: 1
            });
            $container.masonry('appended',
            $newElems, true);
        });
    });
});
})(jQuery) 
</script>
```

If the script is in my footer it works 100%, when I add it into the single js it stops working...

Any ideas on why this is, and how should I load the script the same way from the external js stylesheet as it executes like when inline.

Comment: Either the external JS file doesn't load correctly, or you're loading the scripts in wrong order (this file before jQuery for example), or something else. Do you see errors in the console?

Comment: Hi Juhana - the script is loading into the page, and I have placed this part at the bottom of my combined.js file... at first I loaded the combined.js in the header without the <script> in the combined.js and then added it to the bottom of the js, loading it now in the footer

Comment: Hi @Juhana ha yes you solved it, it were indeed the order in which I placed the script within the combined.js script which were giving the problem! - Thanks a million, how do I mark your comment the answer?

Comment: Also, note that `(function ($) { jQuery(function () { … }); })(jQuery);` could just be `jQuery(function($) { … });`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the starting `<script>`and ending tag `</script>` while using it in a external js file. Also make sure you are including `jQuery` before this js file.